# Continuing to play as Yoon?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, pathfinder-society

Is it possible to continue to play as the pregenerated character Yoon or is she available only for trial runs? This is Yoons character sheet. Note that by continue to use it i mean leveling her as well.

https://goo.gl/images/gNjpef

Comment: @HeyICanChan Based on that link we've been given, Yoon appears to be [the iconic kineticist](http://paizo.com/community/blog/v5748dyo5lhqz?Meet-the-Iconics-Yoon) from [Occult Adventures](http://paizo.com/products/btpy9egu)

Comment: @doppelgreener Yep! I found that same blog entry… that *doesn't* include her character sheet! [It seems one must go through Paizo's purchase process and buy the company's iconics for $0 to get Yoon in official PDF at various levels.](http://paizo.com/products/btpy9a64) ([Yoon also has an AMA thread on the Paizo messageboards.](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2sjyo?Ask-Yoon-ALL-of-your-questions-here))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So far as I can tell, a player can't *adopt* a pregenerated character as his own. That is, the *Guide on Pathfinder Society Organized Play* (ver. 6.0) on Legal Pathfinder Society Characters says

> For modules and Adventure Path content below 9th level, if you do not have a character in the correct level range, you may use a Pathfinder Society pregenerated character [like Yoon]…. You must apply the credit [for having participated in the adventure] to your character as soon as she reaches the level of the pregenerated character played. (29-30)

So you may be able to play Yoon—with all of her unavailable-to-normal-Pathfinder-Society-PCs quirks—several times, but whatever Yoon earns while you play her is later applied to your own actual character. Yoon herself remains unchanged.